# Reading an string from the url in a class in the view (APIView)

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a url like the following in my pattern

```
urlpatterns = [
...
    path('rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/<str:key>', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
...
]
```

I need to be able to pass the key ("MjU:1ggiiI:923vm1cLboPQk9TX1f0aywDWBs8") from this sample url:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/MjU:1ggiiI:923vm1cLboPQk9TX1f0aywDWBs8/

to the following view,:

```
class VerifyEmailView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    allowed_methods = ('POST','GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD')
....
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        '''key is used here'''
        self.kwargs['key'] = serializer.validated_data['key']
        confirmation = self.get_object()
        confirmation.confirm(self.request)
....
```

would someone please advise me how could I access my key in this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
path = request.path
path_vals = path.split('/')
key = path_vals[-2]
```

Answer (score 2):

as you are using url parameters you can get it directly as function parameter in your `get()` see below example:

```
class VerifyEmailView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    allowed_methods = ('POST','GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD')
....
    def get(self, request, key):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        '''key is used here'''
        self.key = key
        confirmation = self.get_object()
        confirmation.confirm(self.request)
....
```

Here you directly get "MjU:1ggiiI:923vm1cLboPQk9TX1f0aywDWBs8" in `key` variable.

For more info check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/) page

Answer (score 0):

while #nishant and #Amit solution works this also should work

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      kwargs=self.kwargs
      key=kwargs.get('key')
```

however in this case Allauth actually complains with url of the form:

```
path('rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/<str:key>', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
```

with such an error:
Exception Value:

TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'

and expects the url of the form:

```
path('rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
```

with this #nishant solution works here,